# Assigning multiple annotation pinColors within the same mapView in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, annotations

so I have a map view with annotations added as users post at different locations. I am attempting to change the pin color to Green, Red or Purple depending on how long its been since the pin was created.

The issue im having here is that all of the pins want to change to one specified color rather than displaying pins with different colors. I can't seem to figure out whats going wrong here. With the example code below it is setting all the pins green, when in reality the only pins that should be green are pins created less than 4 hours ago, red pins are older than 4 hours but younger than 44 hours, and purple pins are older than 44 hours.

any help is appreciated!

```
pinColorQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (dateCreated, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.

                let createdDates = dateCreated as! [PFObject]

                for date in createdDates {
                    let createdAt = date.createdAt as NSDate!
                    let currentDate = NSDate()
                    let expirationDate = currentDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(date.createdAt!)

                    //This is where I attempt to set the pinColor based on age of pin
                    if (expirationDate < 18000) {
                        normalPinView!.pinColor = .Green
                    } else if (expirationDate < 162000) {
                        normalPinView!.pinColor = .Red
                    } else if (expirationDate > 162050) {
                        normalPinView!.pinColor = .Purple
                    }

                }

            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
```

The expirationDate interval is returning correctly, which I checked with a simple `println("\(expirationDate)")`.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with same kind of functionality on mapview but with objective-c. This will not directly change pin color of already added annotation. Work around is somehow you enumerate all your annotation and apply your logic of pincolor, if there is change in pincolor create new annotation with new pincolor but using old data source then remove old annotation and add new annotation at the same place. Personally speaking it will work definitely and it is the actual solution. In my application i am changing pin color as well as pin size if post has comment count more than 10,50 and so on.

Objective-c code: In Some function.

```
for (int i =0; i < [self.mapView.annotations count]; i++)
{
   if ([[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])
{
     CustomAnnotationClass *annotation=[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i];

    if (annotation.expirationDuration <= 18000)
     {
         CustomAnnotationClass *newAnnotation = annotation;
         newAnnotation.pinColor = purple;
         [self.mapView removeAnnotation:[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i]];
         [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
      }

      }
}
```

This is just rough idea, there will be typo error and it is not in swift and instead for loop you can use enumeration.

Comment: Okay so I kind of understand what your saying, but I'm confused as to how I actually put this into code?

Comment: @Zach i have edited my answer, it contains some rough code. if you don't understand let me know i will provide you in swift.

Comment: Can you provide it in Swift? it's very confusing for me :(